# Rewrite rule for pages in one part of site

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a where pages are something like `/admin/adduser` I have .htaccess with this rewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin)\/([A-Za-z]*)$ $1.php?id=$2
```

On one page of my site (/getReading/clientlist) there are pages which I want to display in url to. How can I rewrite rule for this? It should be the same but must consider pages only at one page.

I tried this variant:

```
RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin)\/([A-Za-z]*)\/([0-9]*)$ $1.php?id=$2&page=$3
```

But when I go to simple pages without number in it it says that page is not found. How can I do it?

Here is examples:
`/index/testpage` should be `index?id=testpage` as it is now, but
`/getReading/clientList/1` should be `index?id=clientlist&page=1`

Comment: It is not at all clear what your requirements are. What URL do you want to rewrite and what should it be routed to?

Comment: Updated and added the example. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin)/(\w+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(index|getReadings|admin)/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: gonna test your answer.

Comment: Works perfect! Sory for acepting too long. There were some other duties.